# Google Cloud - Django - OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, django, gcloud, readonly, oserror

I have deployed my django project on google cloud. One module of my app involves uploading files. When I am uploading my files on local server the files are successfully uploading but when I am trying to upload the files from the production server it is giving me the following error:

OSError at /uploadrecords
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/workspace/media/test.pdf'

Following is my code for uploading files and the settings:

```
#views.py    


    image = request.FILES['filerecord']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(image.name, image)
    obj.upfile = fs.url(filename)
    obj.save()
    
    #setting.py

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    #MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

Kindly suggest me a solution

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using App Engine standard.

The file system of hosted apps is constrained:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files

You can use `/tmp` for temporary storage of uploads.

You can want to consider e.g. Google Cloud Storage for persistent storage of files.

Answer (score 0):

The io module provides Python’s main facilities for dealing with various types of I/O.

Try to use it

```
import io

io.BytesIO(some_data)
```